# Difference between Raspbian "latest" and "full latest"

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch

The [Raspbian download page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) seems to have one option more than previous versions. Until now I recall there was only "with Desktop" and "Lite". Now we have

- with desktop and recommended software (1.9 GB zipped, 5.0 GB .img)
- with desktop (1.1 GB zipped, 3.3 GB .img)
- Lite (350 MB zipped)

The description on the site is ambiguous, i.e.

> Raspbian comes pre-installed with plenty of software for education, programming and general use. It has Python, Scratch, Sonic Pi, Java and more.

Obviously this was never true for the Lite version, which could not run Scratch due to the missing window system. With the new options, the question is whether Scratch is recommended software or not.

> The Raspbian with Desktop image contained in the ZIP archive is over 4GB in size [...]

There is no longer "the" image. Now we have two different images which contain desktop.

My question:

If I download the "small" desktop image, which packages would I need to install in order to make it the "full" desktop image with recommended software?

Comment: Old post but gives you some idea: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=229925

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-update-november-2018/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I downloaded both version with release date 2019-04-08. Without doing an upgrade and without Internet connection, I then ran the command `sudo apt list --installed`.

I saved the results in a text file and then diffed the files. The differences are:

```
ant
ant-optional
bluej
claws-mail
claws-mail-i18n
coinor-libcbc3
coinor-libcgl1
coinor-libclp1
coinor-libcoinmp1v5
coinor-libcoinutils3v5
coinor-libipopt1v5
coinor-libosi1v5
docutils-common
erlang-base
erlang-crypto
erlang-syntax-tools
fonts-crosextra-caladea
fonts-crosextra-carlito
fonts-dejavu
fonts-dejavu-extra
fonts-lato
fonts-liberation
fonts-linuxlibertine
fonts-opensymbol
fonts-sil-gentium
fonts-sil-gentium-basic
gcj-6-jre-lib
greenfoot
jackd
jackd2
libabw-0.1-1
libapache-poi-java
libapache-pom-java
libbase-java
libbcmail-java
libbcpkix-java
libbcprov-java
libboost-date-time1.61.0
libboost-date-time1.62.0
libboost-filesystem1.61.0
libboost-iostreams1.61.0
libboost-system1.61.0
libboost-thread1.62.0
libbsh-java
libc-ares2
libcdr-0.1-1
libclucene-contribs1v5
libclucene-core1v5
libcmis-0.5-5v5
libcolamd2
libcommons-codec-java
libcommons-collections3-java
libcommons-logging-java
libcommons-parent-java
libcompfaceg1
libdom4j-java
libe-book-0.1-1
libehcache-java
libeot0
libetonyek-0.1-1
libetpan17
libexiv2-14
libexttextcat-2.0-0
libexttextcat-data
libflute-java
libfonts-java
libformula-java
libfreehand-0.1-1
libgcj-bc
libgcj-common
libgcj17
libgltf-0.0-0v5
libgmime-2.6-0
libgpgme11
libhsqldb1.8.0-java
libhttp-parser2.8
libisorelax-java
libitext-java
libjaxen-java
libjcommon-java
libjdom1-java
libjs-sphinxdoc
libjs-underscore
liblangtag-common
liblangtag1
liblayout-java
libloader-java
liblockfile-bin
liblockfile1
liblog4j1.2-java
libmail-java
libmhash2
libmspub-0.1-1
libmsv-java
libmumps-seq-4.10.0
libmwaw-0.3-3
libmythes-1.2-0
libneon27-gnutls
libodfgen-0.1-1
liborcus-0.11-0
libpagemaker-0.0-0
libpentaho-reporting-flow-engine-java
libpisock9
libpixie-java
libportaudio2
libpq5
libqt5opengl5
libqt5scintilla2-12v5
libqt5scintilla2-l10n
libqwt-qt5-6
libraptor2-0
librasqal3
libraw15
librdf0
librelaxng-datatype-java
libreoffice
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
libreoffice-base
libreoffice-base-core
libreoffice-base-drivers
libreoffice-calc
libreoffice-common
libreoffice-core
libreoffice-draw
libreoffice-gtk
libreoffice-gtk2
libreoffice-help-en-gb
libreoffice-impress
libreoffice-java-common
libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
libreoffice-librelogo
libreoffice-math
libreoffice-nlpsolver
libreoffice-ogltrans
libreoffice-pdfimport
libreoffice-pi
libreoffice-report-builder
libreoffice-report-builder-bin
libreoffice-script-provider-bsh
libreoffice-script-provider-js
libreoffice-script-provider-python
libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb
libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql
libreoffice-style-galaxy
libreoffice-style-tango
libreoffice-systray
libreoffice-wiki-publisher
libreoffice-writer
librepository-java
librevenge-0.0-0
libruby2.3
libsac-java
libsac-java-gcj
libsaxonhe-java
libscsynth1
libsctp1
libserializer-java
libservlet3.1-java
libsuitesparseconfig4
libuv1
libvisio-0.1-1
libwpd-0.10-10
libwpg-0.3-3
libwps-0.4-4
libxerces2-java
libxfont1
libxml-commons-external-java
libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java
libxml-java
libxmlbeans-java
libxom-java
libxpp2-java
libxpp3-java
libyajl2
libyaml-0-2
lp-solve
minecraft-pi
mypy
nodejs
nodejs-doc
nodered
nuscratch
pylint3
python-games
python-minecraftpi
python-sense-emu
python-sense-emu-doc
python3-astroid
python3-asttokens
python3-cairo
python3-docutils
python3-gi-cairo
python3-isort
python3-jedi
python3-lazy-object-proxy
python3-minecraftpi
python3-pygments
python3-pyperclip
python3-roman
python3-sense-emu
python3-thonny
python3-thonny-pi
python3-typed-ast
python3-uno
python3-venv
python3-wrapt
python3.5-venv
qjackctl
rake
realvnc-vnc-viewer
ruby
ruby-did-you-mean
ruby-minitest
ruby-net-telnet
ruby-power-assert
ruby-test-unit
ruby2.3
rubygems-integration
scratch
scratch2
sense-emu-tools
smartsim
sonic-pi
squeak-plugins-scratch
squeak-vm
supercollider-server
uno-libs3
ure
wolfram-engine
wolframscript
xclip
xfonts-100dpi
xfonts-encodings
xfonts-utils
xsel
zip
```

Probably the most noticeable differences are, as mentioned in [the Raspberry forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=229925):

- LibreOffice
- Thonny (a Python IDE)
- Scratch
- Scratch 2
- Sonic Pi
- Minecraft
- Python Games
- SmartSim
- SenseHAT Emulator
- Mathematica (I could not confirm)
- BlueJ
- Greenfoot
- Node-RED
- Claws Mail
- VNC Viewer item

And I would like to add to that list:

- Node JS
- Ruby
- Wolfram Engine
- Zip

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-update-november-2018/

Comment: Yes, I was disappointed to have missed the following, and need to install it myself. LibreOffice, Thonny, Python Games, Node-RED, Node JS, Ruby