# Installing the recommended software after install the desktop only version of raspian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-3b+, raspbian-buster, software-recommendation

I have installed Raspbian Buster without recommended software on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ and I am curious to see what are the recommended software.
What do i have to do to install them on top of the current OS without flashing my SD card again?

What I mean by 'Recommended software' software is the one referred in their [official site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) as *"Raspbian Buster with desktop and recommended software"*

For those who are confused I also want a method of how to install them

Comment: Hello and welcome -- What do you mean by "*what are the recommended software*"?

Comment: Ah, let me see. You remind me a similar question asked a year ago: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97903/difference-between-raspbian-latest-and-full-latest?r=SearchResults&s=1|193.2180.

Comment: I guess the time has come for me to update my one year old "full" list: https://penzu.com/p/82e7b15e.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Raspbian "latest" and "full latest"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97903/difference-between-raspbian-latest-and-full-latest)

Comment: So are you asking what the recommended software is or how to install them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly,

you can click on the raspberry Icon in the upper left of your screen.
a menu should drop down, move your mouse cursor down to "Preferances".

a screen should open to the right of your mouse cursor and you need to
re-position the cursor into this secondary menu.

in this secondary menu, move your cursor down until "Recommended Software"
is highlighted and mouse click on this option.

you will have to wait while the system loads the software 'packages'.
Once that process has completed, you will see a list of the recommended software
the system has located. "All Programs" should be highlighted or you can select a
sub-category by clicking on one.

As an example, click on the sub-catagory "Office". You can then select "LibreOffice" which has a suite of products similar to Microsoft's Office - by clicking in the checkbox, then clicking the "OK" button.
It is a very good addition to have on your RaspberryPi.
Enjoy !